# Code-Profiling non-standard languages (like VBS2 script)

Tags: profiling

I'm finishing up a [VBS2-powered](http://virtualbattlespace.vbs2.com/) game and am about to begin optimizing the code and improve performance.  I can't seem to find any code profiling tools that can analyze the proprietary VBS2 scripting language.  Does anyone have any suggestions for tools I can use to analyze the performance of these scripts, or the processes/threads that make up my game?  At this point, I'm just trying to find any tools that can help me analyze the performance of my application at any level.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VBS2, but can you take stackshots? Tools can help, like **pstack**, but if you just have a debugger with a pause button or ctrl-break, you can do it. Here's a [blow-by-blow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773) of using them for performance tuning. Here's a [short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802).